# MVC - Cant't Navigate to Details View ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Hi In my MVC application I am trying to navigate to Details View

**This is my code in controller**

```
 public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Customer/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NorthWindEntity db = new NorthWindEntity();
        var Data = db.Customers;
        return View(Data);
    }
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        NorthWindEntity db = new NorthWindEntity();
        var Data = db.Customers.Where(e => e.CustomerID == id).Select(e => e).Single();
        return View(Data);
    }
}
```

**This is the code in global asax**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

**This is the code in main page for navigation**

```
 <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",new { id=item.CustomerID }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CustomerID })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CustomerID })%>
        </td>
```

**And I have created Details View 
Like this**

[image]

But the problem is when I am trying to navigate to details view I am getting this error

```
 The resource cannot be found.
 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)
 could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. 
 Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

 Requested URL: /Customer/Details/1
```

I am confused because the page is already there, what was I am missing.?

Answer (score 0):

You will can try rename aspx to cshtml.
Please see your ProviderBinders and Routing in global asax

Comment: How do i find that ..?To be frank I am new to MVC :-).

Comment: rename details.aspx to datails.cshtml

Comment: This is the code on the top of the page for inheritance <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<BasicMVCApplication.Models.Customer>>" %>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25941/discussion-between-simply-denis-and-vijesh)